# Showing the directory of the class in console when I am trying to print something in console

Tags: java, class

This is one class to return required Strings and char:

```
public class Author {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private char gender;

    public Author(){}

    public Author (String name, String email, char gender){

            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.gender = gender;

    }

    public String getName(){        
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail(){           
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){         
        this.email = email;
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return gender;      
    }

    public String toStrnig(){   
        return "Name: "+ name + "\nEmail: "+ email + "\nGender: "+ gender;
    }

}
```

Here is main class to call the name, e-mail and gender.

```
   public class Book {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Author one = new Author("Shohurh", "ghostking@mail.mail", 'm');
            System.out.println(one);
            one.setEmail("nothing");
            System.out.println(one);
        }
}
```

This is the result in console: 
Library.Author@15db9742
Library.Author@15db9742

Would be thankful if you could highlight the wrong area of code:

Comment: `toString()`, not `toStrnig()`. Use `@Override` to make it not happen again.

Comment: what do you mean by "directory of the class"?

Comment: try `getClass().getName()` or `Author.class.getName()` in a `static` context.

Comment: bro, thanx but i already got the answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should overide toString method like that :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it was not working. What was matter?

Comment: You have print the author not just the email or the name. toString method represent the object and are called every times in an object.

Comment: 'You have print the author not just the email or the name' isn't the problem here. What on earth does  'called every times on an object' mean? You haven't identified that the problem was a typo in the name of `toString().`